# Should I read episode I before or after playing Final Fantasy XIII-2?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I have the special edition that brings the episode I novellete but I don't know if I should read it before or after playing the game.

Answer (score 2):

According to the info I have, the novellete is supposed to fill in some blanks between XIII and XIII-2.  Lots of the story gets filled in while you play, so I'd recommend reading it beforehand.

Comment: Thank you very much! You were right, I read it before playing the game.

Comment: Glad you liked it!  Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it helped.